# OpenCV OCR - RobustTextDetection, parameters selection

Tags: opencv, image-processing, ocr

I am using OpenCV's RobustTextDetection to identify words from receipts.
Following are the parameters i have set.

```
param.minMSERArea = 5;
param.maxMSERArea = 40000;
param.cannyThresh1 = 1;
param.cannyThresh2 = 4000;

param.maxConnCompCount = 4000;
param.minConnCompArea = 10;
param.maxConnCompArea = 4000;

param.minEccentricity = 0.02;
param.maxEccentricity = 0.998;
param.minSolidity = 0.45;
param.maxStdDevMeanRatio = 0.5;
```

Following is the image i have used for the experiment.
[image]

Following is the result
[image]

Following are the problems

1. Manual configuration is required
2. Detection of character B is inconsistent
3. Consistent faulty detection of Q, 0, 6, 9, and o,
4. "." for prices are missing

Your comments and advices are deeply appreciated

Comment: sharpen and contrasting do improve the result

Comment: my lovely enhancer that i have come up by myself improved the result too <3. And then i use denoiser. But it is too slow. MY enhancer alone is good enough.